# May Jews do business in non kosher animal food

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals, business, yoreh-deah

The halacha generally prohibits Jews from doing commerce in non kosher foods, although they are not always issur hanaah they are prohibited from regular business in. However, is it permissible for Jews to do commerce in non kosher animal food, not meant for human consumption, such as say dog or cat food?

Comment: Dog food made of kosher ingredients, or dog food made from non-kosher ingredients?

Comment: Consider basar v’chalav

Comment: Many Jews in Alsace (France/Germany) were active for dozens of years in the cattle/horse-trading business - and some of these horses were being eaten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R’ Moshe in [Igros Moshe YD 2:37](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=47) says it is permitted. Obviously, we are not discussing a case of issurei hannah, just the issur sechora.

Answer (score -3):

For milk and meat mixtures, there is a prohibition from benefiting and the bar is not human consumption but dog consumption. You would not be allowed to sell dog cheeseburgers.

For improperly shechted meat, the Torah says to sell it to a non Jew or to give it to a dog. You should be able to sell this as animal feed as well.

There are no special rules about benefiting from other non kosher meat.

A non Jew is prohibited from eating a limb from a live animal. For a Jew, the animals is considered dead when it is shechted. For a non Jew, it is dead when it stops twitching. If you shecht the animal and it is sold and consumed before it stops twitching, that may be a problem.

Comment: Your source makes no sense! How can they sell the carcass of a gored ox if they can't sell non kosher meat!

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%90

Comment: If my cow dies of natural causes, I can sell the carcass. The point is that the Talmud says I should not get in the business of operating a non-kosher-meat store, even if my clientele is 100% non-Jewish. (But one could sell the occasional non-kosher bycatch, for example.) Thus the question -- if it's not okay for my day job to have a rabbit-meat BBQ restaurant selling to non-Jews, can my day job be selling horse meat, in a situation where the intended consumers are all not human?